# Trying to find Date Differences in Excel between multiple enteries

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table of Invoices and Date modified. This gives multiple invoice entries with multiple dates by person. What I am trying to do is find the dates between the first and last entry to give me a time frame on how long it took from start to finish.

See table below:

| Invoice | Entered/Modified | Last modified | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N805844 | 2/5/2024 | Joe | Latest |
| N805844 | 2/5/2024 | Steve | Prior |
| N805844 | 12/28/2024 | Mike | Prior |
| N808961 | 1/4/2024 | Joe | Latest |
| N805961 | 1/3/2024 | Joe | Prior |
| N805961 | 1/2/2024 | Mike | Prior |
| N805961 | 1/2/2024 | Steve | Prior |

I was trying to work on a helper column to identify the Invoice Number and then subtract all date values which should yield a single number - days to completion. I am factoring in the "Latest" and "prior" because it might be helpful.

I've thought about a Max/Min formula on another sheet but I'm not sure how I could that.

I will then pivot this table to show the days to completion. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to accomplish this, I will try to post some ways, as far I know using `Excel Formulas`. There is also one flexible option and that is the use of `POWER QUERY`.

**Using Excel Formulas:**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd> this returns the unique invoices

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A8)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd> this returns the start date as well as the end date

```
=AGGREGATE({15,14},6,B$2:B$8/($F2=A$2:A$8),1)
```

---

• For `#` of days place the following in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=H2-G2+1
```

---

All the above formulas needs to fill down except the one for invoices.

---

**Alternative Way 2**

[image]

---

The following formula is `MS365` Exclusive.

```
=LET(
     _UniqInv, UNIQUE(A2:A8),
     _LastestDate, MAXIFS(B2:B8,A2:A8,_UniqInv),
     _PriorDate, MINIFS(B2:B8,A2:A8,_UniqInv),
     _DataBody, HSTACK(_UniqInv, _PriorDate, _LastestDate, _LastestDate-_PriorDate+1),
     VSTACK({"Unique Invoice","Prior Date","Latest Date","# Of Days"},_DataBody))
```

---

- Using `UNIQUE()` function to return unique invoices.
- Using `MAXIFS()` to return the latest date.
- Using `MINIFS()` to return the start date.
- Using `HSTACK()` to merge all the three above as well as doing a subtraction with the second & third variable to return `#` of days. (**Note:** No of days are all prior dates inclusive, if you dont want the same then exclude the `+1`).
- Lastly, using `VSTACK()` to append the whole along with a header.

---

Another way is using the new beta enabled function in `MS365` - `GROUPBY()`

```
=LET(
     _Data, DROP(GROUPBY(A2:A8,B2:B8,HSTACK(MIN,MAX),0,0),1),
     _NoOfDays, INDEX(_Data,,3)-INDEX(_Data,,2)+1,
     VSTACK({"Unique Invoice","Prior Date","Latest Date","# Of Days"},
     HSTACK(_Data,_NoOfDays)))
```

---

And this can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Invoice"}, {{"Start_Date", each List.Min([#"Entered/Modified"]), type datetime}, {"End_Date", each List.Max([#"Entered/Modified"]), type datetime}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "No_Of_Days", each Duration.Days([End_Date]-[Start_Date])+1),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Invoice", type text}, {"Start_Date", type date}, {"End_Date", type date}, {"No_Of_Days", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

---

### [image]

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Comment: ,, nice approach U get +10 ☺

Comment: Thank you so much! This is extremely helpful. In the first section - the excel formula - how does it apply to G2 and H2? I keep getting the same result?

Comment: @TimValli what is you excel version may I know that please? If you are using `Excel 2010+` till `Excel 2019` then you need to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode, formula applied only in `G2`. Did it with one formula for start date and last date but if you are reluctant to use that way, then can use `MAXIFS()` or `MINIFS()` or `MAX()/MIN()`+`IF()`

Comment: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019

Comment: I'm still not getting the end date to appear. I know I can change the last number on the AGGREGATE - the "k" value, but it's not 100% accurate if I don't know how many times it was touched.

Comment: Yes. I used: =AGGREGATE(15,6,'Invoice Transaction Detail'!B2:B4293/($A2='Invoice Transaction Detail'!A2:A4293),1) for start date and =AGGREGATE(14,6,'Invoice Transaction Detail'!B2:B4293/($A2='Invoice Transaction Detail'!A2:A4293),1) for the end date:

Comment: Nice to know you have resolved. Thank you very much @TimValli =)